# Alternative statement for deprecated rendererV2().symbols()?

Tags: pyqgis

In my QGIS python plugin, this code triggers a deprecated warning (QgsFeatureRendererV2.symbols() is deprecated) :

```
myLayer.rendererV2().symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, mySymbolLayer)
```

What is the alternative up-to-date way to modify a layer's symbology ?
The doc says :

> use symbols( QgsRenderContext& context ) instead

but I can't find the correct way to follow that advice...

Comment: I get this message with QGIS 2.14 and 2.18

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/245940/edit) your question to include how you want to change the symbology of your layer? For QGIS 2.18, I used [this post](https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2014/03/04/symbology-of-vector-layers-in-qgis-python-plugins/) to make symbology changes.

Comment: Yes, it's the same code as mine, it can be found in many tutorials on the net, and it actually work, it's just that i gives a deprecated warning I would like to get rid of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer to my question :

```
objLayer.rendererV2().symbols2(QgsRenderContext())[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, symbolLayer)
```

No deprecated warning anymore with this code.